# PySpark UDF not recognizing number of arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have defined a Python function "DateTimeFormat" which takes three arguments

> 1. Spark Dataframe column which has date formats (String)
> 2. The input format of column's value like yyyy-mm-dd (String)
> 3. The output format i.e. the format in which the input has to be returned like yyyymmdd (String)

I have now registered this function as UDF in Pyspark.
`udf_date_time = udf(DateTimeFormat,StringType())`

I am trying to call this UDF in dataframe select and it seems to be working fine as long as the input format and output are different like below

`df.select(udf_date_time('entry_date',lit('mmddyyyy'),lit('yyyy-mm-dd')))`

But it fails, when the input format and output format are same with the following error

`df.select('exit_date',udf_date_time('exit_date',lit('yyyy-mm-dd'),lit('yyyy-mm-dd')))`

> > "DateTimeFormat" takes exactly 3 arguments. 2 given

But I'm clearly sending three arguments to the UDF

I have tried the above example on Python 2.7 and Spark 2.1

The function seems to work as expected in normal Python when input and output formats are the same

```py
>>>DateTimeFormat('10152019','mmddyyyy','mmddyyyy')
'10152019'
>>>
```

But the below code is giving error when run in SPARK

```py
import datetime
# Standard date,timestamp formatter
# Takes string date, its format and output format as arguments
# Returns string formatted date
def DateTimeFormat(col,in_frmt,out_frmt):   
    date_formatter ={'yyyy':'%Y','mm':'%m','dd':'%d','HH':'%H','MM':'%M','SS':'%S'}
    for key,value in date_formatter.items():
        in_frmt = in_frmt.replace(key,value)
        out_frmt = out_frmt.replace(key,value)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(col,in_frmt).strftime(out_frmt)
```

Calling UDF using the code below

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
# Create SPARK session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateChanger").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(file_path)

# Registering UDF
udf_date_time = udf(DateTimeFormat,StringType())

df.select('exit_date',udf_date_time('exit_date',lit('yyyy-mm-dd'),lit('yyyy-mm-dd'))).show()
```

CSV file input [Input file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oq4bgoE-qleOK0c2hexSFClk0Av_-EEK)

Expected result is the command

```
df.select('exit_date',udf_date_time('exit_date',lit('yyyy-mm-dd'),lit('yyyy-mm-dd'))).show()
```

should NOT throw any error like 
**DateTimeFormat takes exactly 3 arguments but 2 given**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a better way to do this but you can try the following.

Here I have assumed that you want your dates to a particular format and have set the default for the output format (`out_frmt='yyyy-mm-dd'`) in your `DateTimeFormat` function

I have added a new function called `udf_score` to help with conversions. That might interest you

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit


df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["10-15-2019"],
    ["10-16-2019"],
    ["10-17-2019"],
], ['exit_date'])

import datetime
def DateTimeFormat(col,in_frmt,out_frmt='yyyy-mm-dd'):
    date_formatter ={'yyyy':'%Y','mm':'%m','dd':'%d','HH':'%H','MM':'%M','SS':'%S'}
    for key,value in date_formatter.items():
        in_frmt = in_frmt.replace(key,value)
        out_frmt = out_frmt.replace(key,value)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(col,in_frmt).strftime(out_frmt)

def udf_score(in_frmt):
    return udf(lambda l: DateTimeFormat(l, in_frmt))

in_frmt = 'mm-dd-yyyy'
df.select('exit_date',udf_score(in_frmt)('exit_date').alias('new_dates')).show()
+----------+----------+
| exit_date| new_dates|
+----------+----------+
|10-15-2019|2019-10-15|
|10-16-2019|2019-10-16|
|10-17-2019|2019-10-17|
+----------+----------+
```